# Is there a way of storing vectors of varying size in context as discrete states

Tags: drake

I am working with compass gait and I am looking at storing some motion primitives/obstacle descriptions. Since all the functions in the class are constant, I cannot add a variable to the class to store this information. Hence I was wondering if there was a way in which I could store this in the context as discrete state of varying size.

1)Is it feasible to take this route or is there a better way of doing it?

2)If it is a feasible route, how do I create discrete variables of varying length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no mechanism, currently, for variable-length vectors.  You can work around this by enlarging your state space.  We do have the compass gait example in c++, though if you want to see a hybrid system that does this, and in python, you could look at https://github.com/RussTedrake/underactuated/blob/master/src/spring_loaded_inverted_pendulum/plant.py